# Why Firebase database getUid doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Initially, I wrote a code to store the value in Firebase realtime database.

```
mDbRef = mDatabase.getReference().child("Users");
mDbRef.child("name").setValue(rname);
mDbRef.child("email").setValue(remail);
```

The child value was stored under its Uid in 'Users' child.

Then I changed the code to

```
String name = userName.getText().toString();
mDbRef = mDatabase.getReference().child("Users").child(name);
mDbRef.child("name").setValue(rname);
mDbRef.child("email").setValue(remail);
```

Now, the child value was stored under its name in 'Users' child.

Now I have two issues,

1. If I add same name with different sub child values, it was not accepted. How to rectify it?
2. I wrote the following code to check user before starting an activity.

```
    public void checkUserExists () {
        final String user_id = Objects.requireNonNull(uAuth.getCurrentUser()).getUid();
        mDbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(user_id)) {
                    startActivity(new Intent (LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {        
            }
        });
    }
```

The new Intent activity was working fine when the child was under Uid. When it was changed to 'name' in lieu of Uid, the intent activity doesn't start. But if I restart the app after closing it, it directly goes to Home activity. What should be done to rectify the issue?

Comment: What do you mean through "it was not accepted"?

Comment: 1.- If I add same name with different sub child values, it was not accepted. How to rectify it? --- If you add the same name you gonna replace the current values, you are using "name" as key

Comment: Instead of replacing, I want to add the same name with different sub child values. What should be done? If I add push(), then it is added under existing 'name' child with Uid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest something like that:

```
String key = mDatabase.child("users").push().getKey();
// key is generated by Firebase and is unique
mDbRef = mDatabase.getReference().child("users").child(key);
mDbRef.child("name").setValue(rname);
mDbRef.child("email").setValue(remail);
```

And check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data?authuser=0)

happy to help!